# MySQL - Select last value by day for the last 7 days using multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, date, statistics, inner-join

Here's my current database:

```
TABLE profileData
+---------------------------+
| profileID | name          |
+----+----------------------+
| 1         | Stackoverflow |
| 2         | Stackexchange |
| 3         | Askubuntu     |
+-----------+---------------+

TABLE stats
+----+-----------+------------------------------+
| id | profileID | sCount | ts                  |
+----+-----------+--------+---------------------+
| 1  | 1         | 1      | 2013-10-04 00:00:01 |
| 2  | 2         | 5      | 2013-10-04 00:00:01 |
| 3  | 3         | 8      | 2013-10-04 00:00:01 |
| 4  | 1         | 10     | 2013-10-05 00:00:01 |
| 5  | 2         | 50     | 2013-10-05 00:00:01 |
| 6  | 1         | 100    | 2013-10-06 00:00:01 |
| 7  | 2         | 500    | 2013-10-06 00:00:01 |
| 8  | 1         | 101    | 2013-10-06 13:00:01 |
| 9  | 2         | 501    | 2013-10-06 19:00:01 |
| 10 | 3         | 17     | 2013-10-06 05:00:01 |
| 11 | 1         | 100    | 2013-10-09 00:00:01 |
| 12 | 2         | 500    | 2013-10-09 00:00:01 |
+----+-----------+------- +---------------------+

TABLE users
+--------+-----------+
| userID | profileID |
+--------------------+
| 1337   | 1         |
| 1337   | 2         |
+--------+-----------+
```

What i need is the following:

Select all profiles from the table "users" and get the names of them + the last entry of every day from the table "stats" for these profiles for the last 7 days. So, the expected result is

```
+---------------+--------+---------------------+
| name          | sCount | ts                  |
+---------------+--------+---------------------+
| Stackoverflow | 1      | 2013-10-04 00:00:01 |
| Stackexchange | 5      | 2013-10-04 00:00:01 |
| Stackoverflow | 10     | 2013-10-05 00:00:01 |
| Stackexchange | 50     | 2013-10-05 00:00:01 |
| Stackoverflow | 101    | 2013-10-06 13:00:01 |
| Stackexchange | 501    | 2013-10-06 19:00:01 |
| Stackoverflow | 100    | 2013-10-09 00:00:01 |
| Stackexchange | 500    | 2013-10-09 00:00:01 |
+---------------+--------+---------------------+
```

I ended up with this statement:

```
SELECT
    profileData.name,
    stats.scount,
    stats.ts
FROM
    users
INNER JOIN profiles ON 
    users.profileID = profiles.profileID
INNER JOIN
        (
SELECT t1.profileID, t1.sCount, t1.ts
FROM stats t1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT MAX(ts) maxi
FROM stats
GROUP BY DATE(ts)
        ) a2 ON t1.ts = a2.maxi) stats ON
            users.profileID = stats.profileID
WHERE
    users.userID = 1337 AND DATE(stats.ts) >= DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
ORDER BY users.userID, stats.ts
```

This worked partially. However, this statement seems to be an overkill and it's not working anymore.

I've also tried to select `MAX(ts)`. That worked, but the result didn't contain the correspondending `sCount` value.

So, i'm looking for THE solution of my problem and i hope, anyone can help me with this.

Oh and it has to be a pure SQL solution, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like that, which is not that far from what you did.

```
select p.name,
       s.scount,
       s.ts
from profileData p
inner join users u on u.profileID = p.profileID
inner join stats s on s.profileID = p.profileID
inner join (select max(ts) as maxTs, profileID
            from stats
            where DATE(stats.ts) >= DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
            group by profileID, DATE(ts)) as mx
         on s.profileID = mx.profileID and mx.maxTs = s.ts
where u.userID = 1337
```

see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db8d3/3)

Comment: Oh wow. That really seems to work and just confirms, that i was right with the "overkill". Tyvm.

Answer (score 0):

What about this (EXPLAIN is better) because less FULL tables scan are needed..
But you really need indexes

```
SELECT 
   profileData.name
 , stats.sCount
 , MAX(ts) ts

FROM 
 stats

INNER JOIN
 users
ON
 stats.profileID = users.profileID

INNER JOIN
 profileData
ON
 users.profileID = profileData.profileID

WHERE
  users.userID = 1337
 AND
  DATE(stats.ts) >= DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))

GROUP BY
   profileData.name
 , stats.profileID ASC
 , stats.sCount ASC

ORDER BY 
 ts ASC
;
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db8d3/51

Comment: Shouldn't the GROUP BY not be `stats.profileID, DATE(ts)`? However, thanks for that.

Comment: This is correct http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db8d3/59   read here http://www.dbasquare.com/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/ why

Comment: No thats not correct.. profileData.name will then be random and can result to an wrong value.. this is way your should always configure your MySQL server with sql_mode = ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db8d3/62